(Vietnam 2007) Given a regular 2007-gon, find smallest positive integer k so we when we pick any k vertices, there are four consecutive ones
Here's the complete problem statement.

Given a regular $2007$-gon, find the smallest positive integer $k$ such that among any $k$ vertices of the polygon there are $4$ with the property that the convex quadrilateral they form shares $3$ sides with the polygon.

This is from Problem Solving Methods in combinatorics Chapter $2$, I understand well why this is equivalent to choosing four consecutive points, I am also able to construct a counter example with $2007-\lfloor\frac{2007}{4}\rfloor-1=1505$ elements by removing multiples of four and $2007$ itself. But I am not quite sure how pigeonhole principle shows $k=1506$ must work
Here's the suggested solution

Number the vertices of the polygon from $1$ to $2007$. What we want is
that any set of $k$ vertices contains at least $4$ consecutive ones. Consider the 4-tuples
of consecutive vertices. Each vertex uses $4$ of these $4$-tuples. Thus if $4k>3 · 2007$
there is a 4-tuple with 4 of the k vertices. That is, if $k ≥ 1506$ the condition we want
is met. To see that $1506$ is the minimum, it is enough to take all the vertices, except
the multiples of $4$ and $2007$. That way we get $1505$ vertices with no $4$ consecutive
ones


We define $2007$ pigeonholes as each being one vertex and the next three clockwise.  Each vertex belongs to four of the pigeonholes.  To avoid four vertices in a row being selected we can only have three pigeons in any one hole.  The maximum number of pigeons is then $3 \cdot 2007=6021$.  If we select $1506$ vertices we have $4 \cdot 1506=6024$ pigeons, which exceeds the maximum number, so there must be at least one pigeonhole with four pigeons.

Let me explain the same answer with another approach!
Consider a circle With vertices $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, ... , a_{2007}$
Now just choose $a_1, a_2, a_3$ leave $a_4$ then again choose the next three which are $a_5, a_6, a_7$ leave $a_8$ 
Notice how $a_{4k}$ is always being left
According to this $a_4, a_8, a_{12}, .... , a_{2004}$ will all be left
Then choose $a_{2005}, a_{2006}$ leave $a_{2007}$, now you have a circle with 1505 chosen vertices with groups of three together, such that if you chose one more you will surely get a group of 4 consecutive vertices.
Thus at max 1505 can be chosen safely, but one more will make it to have 4 consecutive vertices
Thus you have to chose 1506 vertices to have a consecutive of 4 vertices. (Draw a circle, mark $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8$ and last three vertices to understand better)
